# can't get control using FindControl in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't find the dropdown list on row updating:
DropDown list is in **EditTemplate**

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Clear();

    string op = "1";
    try
    {
        DropDownList ddl = GridView1.FindControl("ddlprioridade") as DropDownList;
        op = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
    catch { }
    ....
}
```

This ddl is allways **null** and i can't solve this!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584175/how-to-find-control-in-edit-item-template

Comment: no, its different! :(

Comment: A couple of nit picks: 1) A `try` with an empty `catch` should only be used for debugging code. It should never make it to production; 2) The `SelectedValue` property of a DropDownList object is already a string. No need to call `ToString()` here. Also I agree with @Severiano about this not being a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
var dropDown  = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlprioridade") as DropDownList;
```