# How to get selected cell value of a GridView after filtration. ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sorting, aspxgridview

I have a GridView through which I am displaying some books details and it can be filtered based on book attributes. The problem is this if I filter some books and try to edit one of them the editor pick the id of overall row value not the new one.   `var id = Convert.ToInt32(gridview.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text);` I am getting index value through this

```
 <div class="col">
            <asp:GridView OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView3_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView3_RowCancelingEdit" 
                         class="table table-striped table-bordered" ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id" 
              
                           HeaderStyle-BackColor="#95daa4" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" >
                <Columns >
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ControlStyle-Width="26px" ControlStyle-CssClass="linkGVE"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  DataField="Id"  HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id">
                        <ControlStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="linkGVE"/>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True"/>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" class="animated bounceInRight"  Text='<%# Eval("BookName") %>' Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="18px"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br/>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <span>
                                                    <b>Province -</b><span>&nbsp;</span>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Province") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <b>Subject - </b>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>'> </b></asp:Label>
                                                &nbsp;| <b>Categories -</b>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Categorey") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                &nbsp;| <b>PackageName -</b>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PackageName") %>'></asp:Label>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <b>CategoricalTitle -</b>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoricalTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-2 " style="margin-top: 25px; text-align: center;">

                                        <asp:Image class="img-fluid" BorderWidth="2px"  BorderColor="#82aeb1"   ID="Image1" Height="100px" Width="120px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "http://0.0.0.0/Pictures/" + Eval("PictureURL") %>'/>
                                        <a href='<%# "http://0.0.0.0.0/PDF/" + Eval("PDFURL") %>' style="font-size: 11px;color: black">Download</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try finding control is easier then finding cells because cell is created if you put any container before the control.

You can try `FindControl` rather than reading the cell as below
[how to find control in edit item template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584175/how-to-find-control-in-edit-item-template)

```
GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("control");
```

and cast it accordingly.
Also if it is a primary key put into `data keys` of `gridview` and get it from there. Example [Get DataKey values in GridView RowCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818203/get-datakey-values-in-gridview-rowcommand)

Also hopefully you are properly binding data to gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I did not applied ispostback condition on page reload. as soon as I applied the condition my code begin to work. Thanks